# Ember data sending unnecessary request when a resource is created for the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I am using latest version of ember and ember-data in Rails. I have resources like `blogs`, `topics`, `users` in my app. A `user` has many `topics` and `blogs`.

- When I create a topic for the first time. The ember data, sends this `"/api/topics?ids%5B%5D=1"` after creating the resource. (where 1 is the id of the topic that was created).
  But this weird request does not happen once a resource has been created.
- The same happens when i create `blog` for the first time.

I have the adapter set as

```
 App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({ namespace: 'api' });
```

I believe the issue is with the json output made by `Active model serializer`, whose output is  `blogs: []` and `topics: []`, I believe this is the format expected by ember-data when there are no data in the hasMany relationship array. Did I miss something else?

Comment: Hi Vysakh, I'm having the same problem you described, did you find out what's causing it?

Comment: Maybe you should file a bug against the DS.ActiveModelAdapter in Ember Data then? Active Model Serializer should be replying with HEAD and no content, but it should supply the location of the newly created resource, surely, otherwise how can Ember Data know its ID...